# Example of a continuous map $r : X →Y$ such that $r(x) = x$ for each $x \in Y$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = [-1 , 1] \times [-1 , 1]$ and $Y = \{0\} \times [-\tfrac12, \tfrac12]$. Give an
example of a continuous map $r : X \to Y$ such that $r(x) = x$ for each $x \in Y$.

---

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Help me please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z=\{{0\}}\times[-1,1]$. Can you find a continuous map $f:X\to Z$ such that $f(a)=a$ for all $a$ in $Z$? And then compose it with a continuous map from $Z$ to $Y$ fixing each element of $Y$?

Comment: is the function $f(x,y)=(0,y)$  applicable here?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I can not find the another function from Z to Y.help me please.

Comment: You can map $(0,z)$ to $(0,1/2)$ for $z\ge1/2$, to $(0,z)$ for $-1/2\le z\le1/2$, and to $(0,-1/2)$ for $z\le-1/2$.